# Pure CSS solution for keeping child displayed when there's a hover gap between it's parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a traditional case of a menu with dropdowns that appear on hover. My design requires me to add spacing between the parent menu link  and the dropdown. As expected, this newly created gap between the parent and child prevents the child from staying displayed. I was wondering if there was a pure CSS solution to get this to work.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-width: 210px;
  padding: 26px 14px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:before {
  content: "";
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    Hover over me!

    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Dropdown Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `margin` with transparent top border. However, for this to work, you'll also need to clip the background to the `padding-box`, and use the `drop-shadow` filter instead of `box-shadow`:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  border-radius: 2px; 
  /** box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); **/
  display: none;
  /** border: 6px solid transparent; **/
  min-width: 210px;
  padding: 26px 14px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  
  /** what you need to change **/
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}

.dropdown:before {
  content: "";
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    Hover over me!

    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Dropdown Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why exactly is the padding-box, and filter needed here? From a technical perspective.

Comment: Padding box prevents the background from appearing under the transparent border. And the filter creates a shadow around the visible shape and not the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a transparent pseudo, so the area hovered is increased.

for infos :old IEs required an `opacity:0.001` , it would not catch hover on entirely transparent elements.some nowdays browsers might have this issue.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.menu-item:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.dropdown {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-width: 210px;
  padding: 26px 14px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:before {
  content: "";
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    Hover over me!

    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Dropdown Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution of your problem. i just add comment in css what i am changing please review it once.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px 0px; /*newly added*/
}

.menu-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;  /*update value*/
  min-width: 210px;
  padding: 26px 14px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:before {
  content: "";
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff #fff transparent transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    Hover over me!
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Dropdown Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```